# Ajax gets stuck in the beforeSend phase and does not send data to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a bit of an issue here - I am quite familiar with PHP, but a novice where it concerns jquery and ajax and I have an issue on which I am breaking my teeth on for a week now, so I wonder if you could help me.
I have a big form with about 25 fields to fill in by users in order to create their profile page on my site. I am using jquery to validate all required fields and want to use Ajax to post the data to PHP which then inserts it in a table on the DB. 
The problem is that Ajax gets stuck in the "beforeSend" routine and does not send the values of the fields to PHP and nothing gets inserted. What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

(form has the id "creaform" and the code contains a bunch of validation code which all works and is irrelevant for the questions, so I left that out)

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#createbtn").click(function (e) {
var self = this;

$.ajax({

    type : "POST",
    url  : "profilereg.php", 
    data : $('#creaform').serialize(),
    beforeSend : function() {
    $(self).hide();
    $('#creastatus').html( "<img src='mysuperduperanimatedgif.gif'/>" );
    },
    success : function(html){
                var response = "Your data has been saved. You will now be taken to your profile page.
                $('#creastatus').html( response );

            }

            });
            }
            });
            });
```

And here is the receiving PHP file:

(be aware that this is still in the development phase - once this is working, I will add protection agains sql injection to the PHP - first want to have it working)

```
include("db_conx.php");

$_uname = "TestUser";
$_fname = $_POST['fname'];
$_lname = $_POST['lname'];
$_email = $_POST['email'];
$_wmail = $_POST['wmail'];
$_gender = $_POST['gender'];
$_country = $_POST['country'];
$_dob = $_POST['datepicker'];
$_aboutme = $_POST['aboutme'];
$_genre1 = $_POST['genre1'];
$_genre2 = $_POST['genre2'];
$_genre3 = $_POST['genre3'];
$_style = $_POST['style'];

$today = date("d M Y, G:i");
$_lastvisit = $today;

$sql = "INSERT INTO `uuu`(`username`, `fname`, `lname`, 
`email`, `wriyonmail`, `gender`, `dob`, `country`, `genre1`, `genre2`, 
`genre3`, `style`, `lavis`, `aboutme`) VALUES ('$_uname', '$_fname', 
'$_lname', '$_email', '$_wmail', '$_gender', '$_dob', '$_country', 
'$_genre1', '$_genre2', '$_genre3', '$_style', '$_lastvisit', '$_aboutme')";
```

Again, what is wrong with this  - it gets stuck in the beforeSend display of the animated gif. When I remove the beforeSend, it just does not do anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated :) Thanks!

John

Comment: add an error function then edit your question with the result from the js console in your browser: `error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
}`

Comment: unless you have `self` defined somewhere: `$(self).hide();` will try to hide the `window` object, also you are missing a double quote in your success method and an extra curly brace which will cause an error and your ajax method will not execute at all

Comment: @Patrick the $(self) refers to the button, I have that defined right at the start of the script - forgot to add it to the example. Will do so now. Thanks!

Comment: Added the definition of the "self" variable.

Comment: If the typos are not the problem then you will have to do as user574632 suggests and add in an error function and check the console for an error log

Comment: Ok will try that - nearly overlooked that one. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: Maybe it's the placement of the error? Pls remember that I am a novice to this material and still make stupid errors. This is how I positioned the error function within the code. Let me know if I did sth wrong there: success : function(html){
     var response = "Your data has been saved. You will now be taken to your profile page.";
    $('#creastatus').html( response );
    

   }
   error: function(data, errorThrown) 
   { 
   console.log(textStatus, errorThrown); 
   }
   });
   }
   });
   }); NB: that single curly bracket 2 up from the bottome is there bc that marks the end of validation

Comment: Are there any error messages in your browser console?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
var response = "Your data has been saved. You will now be taken to your profile page.
```

to

```
var response = "Your data has been saved. You will now be taken to your profile page."
```

You seem to be missing the closing quotation mark which will cause a script error

Comment: Tried that too and unfortunately the result is the same :(

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#createbtn").click(function (e) {

    $.ajax({

        type : "POST",
        url  : "profilereg.php", 
        data : $('#creaform').serialize(),
        beforeSend : function() {
                $(self).hide();
                $('#creastatus').html( "<img src='mysuperduperanimatedgif.gif'/>" );
        },
        success : function(html){
                var response = "Your data has been saved. You will now be taken to your profile page.";
                $('#creastatus').html( response );

        }

        });

    });

});
```

Comment: still missing a double quote on the `var response` line

Comment: I tried that and unfortunately it still gets stuck at displaying the beforeSend image.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for getting back at you guys so late - been very busy last couple of days. I have fixed this issue by making it just a standard HTML and PHP-post with some jquery functionality hanging around it to give the user the IMPRESSION that ajax is doing the thing. It waits before submitting, showing a please wait thingie and them redirects to the page it's supposed to go. It inserts the data in all tables, except one, but I will figure that out. In the meantime thanks a million for your replies and efforts to try to solve this. Thanks!